# Application force closes on call

Tags: android

I have This application that "runs it the background" well its supposed to. the problem is when I get a phone call the application forcecloses. How would I get it to truly run in background?

Comment: Is the application using an activity or a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a service if you want a long running application to run in the background. Use the activity to start and stop it. Then when the phone activity is launched, your application will still be running. Service lifecycles do not depend on the Activity being in the foreground

Comment: So if I change the application to a Service it will still run like an Activity?

Comment: @Christian, You need to change it to a Service. Then you need a way to start and stop it. I'd suggest a simple activity with a start/stop button. Then you can start the service and it'll run in the background until you turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Logcat Recorder](http://www.appbrain.com/app/logcat-recorder/org.sacnoth.logcatrecorder) to troubleshoot similar issues in the past. The app collects log messages when the phone is not plugged in to a computer for debugging. Force closing means an uncaught exception was thrown. A call stack will show up in the log.